# Do I need at least 3 machines to be able to work on CoreOS?

Tags: docker, coreos

This is a strange question, but I can't find an answer to it: can I use CoreOS on one machine? Many guides/docs on the internet mention 3 machines. Or can I use it on 2 machines? I'm familiar with CoreOS basics, I know the theory behind it, but I haven't used it yet.

Comment: of course you can do it with one machine. any particular idea why they should be 3?

Comment: I've encountered couple of guides, like the one from [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-coreos-cluster-on-digitalocean) that tell you to create 3 machines. Or [Deis](http://deis.io/), PaaS solution, says you need 3 machines to run it. I just couldn't consider it a coincidence, that the number 3 is appearing so often.

Comment: Are you asking about running CoreOS, or running a CoreOS cluster?

Comment: I'm just asking if there's a limitation regarding a number of machines running either CoreOS alone as a system, or CoreOS as a machine cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run as many or few CoreOS machines as required for your project or needs. The 3 or more machines comes from the [clustering requirements](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/admin_guide.html#optimal-cluster-size) for etcd, a tool that's included in CoreOS and a tool that many other projects use. The tl;dr is that etcd operates on a majority scheme to ensure data is consistent across the cluster, and you need an odd number (3,5,7,9) of machines to operate in the most efficient manner.

etcd (and CoreOS) can be run on a single machine for dev environments and other testing when you don't need high availability or fault tolerance.